# Pasar de Linq a Sql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Tengo la siguiente expresion de Linq:

```
Tabla.Skip(ind_pag).Take(cant_filas).ToList()
```

Como sería en MySql???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso es un query con paginación, los métodos `Skip` y `Take` indican cuantas filas omitir y cuantas seleccionar respectivamente.  En MySQL esto se expresa con `LIMIT`

```
SELECT columna1, columna2, ...
FROM Tabla
LIMIT @ind_pag, @cant_filas
```